# checking if current time is between two times in HHmmss format in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, ksh

I have a main script that calls doSomeWork.sh each and every 10 mins.

But the condition is that the doSomeWork.sh should not run between 23:30:00 to 03:00:00.

I have made my script to look something like the below.

```
#!/bin/ksh
prodStartTime="030000"
prodEndTime="233000"

currentTime=`date +"%H%M%S"`
echo $prodStartTime
echo $prodEndTime
echo $currentTime
while true
do
if [[ $currentTime -ge $prodStartTime && $currentTime -le $prodEndTime ]];
then
      ./doSomeWork.sh
else
 echo Do Nothing
fi
sleep 600
done
```

UPDATE: Now I have the code working by checking production timings instead of night mode timings(See edit history). But looks like my script is considering the values as Octal as suggested by "twalberg" in the comments. Could someone help me how to take care of these values?

I simply need a way to ensure that my script runs between the specified time span.

Comment: There's no reason to use echo for those assignments, just assign them. `nightModeStartTime=230000; nightModeEndTime=033000`

Comment: What about this isn't working? Also it might make sense (when you hit the blackout window) to sleep for longer (possibly even nearly the full length of the window all at once) to avoid looping so often during the window.

Comment: Have you considered that your `033000` (and any result from `date` that has leading zeros) is likely being interpreted as an octal number? You don't really explain how it's not working, so that's just a guess, though... That would be the case in `bash`, but I don't know if the version of `ksh` you're working with would do that or not.

Comment: Script, as it is shown will not run `./doSomeWork.sh` between 23:00:00 and 03:30:00 (not as You write 23:30:00 and 03:00:00), if that is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I should be calculating the current time inside the loop. But I have calculated only once outside of the loop and using the same value through out the day.

The script should be like.

```
#!/bin/ksh
prodStartTime="030000"
prodEndTime="233000"

echo $prodStartTime
echo $prodEndTime
echo $currentTime
while true
do
currentTime=`date +"%H%M%S"`
if [[ $currentTime -ge $prodStartTime && $currentTime -le $prodEndTime ]];
then
      ./doSomeWork.sh
else
 echo Do Nothing
fi
sleep 600
done
```

Somehow this silly mistake was not visible to my eyes.

Comment: @MarkReed Didn't wanted to blame anyone. It was just a mockery on myself. Edited out the answer for better understanding.

Answer (score 6):

Don't compare them numerically (`-ge`, `-le`); just compare them as strings.  Since `ksh` doesn't have `>=` and `<=`, you can use the equivalent `! <` and `! >` instead.

```
if [[ ! "$currentTime" < "$prodStartTime" && ! "$currentTime" > "$prodEndTime" ]]; then
  ./doSomeWork.sh
fi
```

But since we're negating, it might be clearer if we apply DeMorgan's Law and only negate once:

```
if [[ ! ( "$currentTime" < "$prodStartTime" || "$currentTime" > "$prodEndTime" ) ]]; then
   ./doSomeWork.sh
fi
```

In any case, when using `<` and `>`, there's no interpretation of the strings as numbers (octal or otherwise) to worry about.  As long as all the times have the same number of digits, the string comparison will produce the right answer.

Comment: Revoking the acceptance of the answer as my scripts logic was wrong not the syntax.

Comment: You should accept this answer, and not your own: despite the gotcha which you corrected, your script is still wrong because it's comparing the values as numbers (and indeed sometimes octal numbers and sometimes as decimal numbers) when as @Mark Read notes, they should be compared as strings.  What you now have _might_ work, but only by accident.

Comment: @NormanGray The octal interpretation in ksh is being handled internally by stripping 0s. see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3192381/2557818

Answer (score 1):

You could also do it on easy way..

```
#!/bin/bash

prodStart="132000"
prodEnd="151500"

while [[ ! $(( `date +"%H%M%S"` )) < "$prodStart" && ! $(( `date +"%H%M%S"` )) > "$prodEnd" ]];
do
        echo "Do something..."
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
startTime="80000"
endTime="200000"
curTime=$(date  +"%H%M%S" | bc)
echo "startTime : "$startTime
echo "endTime : "$endTime
echo "currentTime :"$curTime
echo "curTime <  endTime and  curTime > startTime then don't execute"
# Messages will be sent only between 8AM to 8PM
if [[ ! ( $curTime -lt  "$endTime" && $curTime -gt "$startTime" ) ]];
then
echo "Don't Execute"
else
echo "Execute"
fi
```